# Error when trying to install package from GitHub

Tags: r, github, installation, package

I am trying to install a package from my own repository in order to test if the functions work. The link to the repository is here: https://github.com/hharder74/SampleMeansII. When I try to install it using the following code:

```
devtools::install_github("hharder74/SampleMeansII")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub: HTTP error 404. Not Found Did you spell the repo owner (`hharder74`) and repo name (`SampleMeansII`) correctly? - If spelling is correct, check that you have the required permissions to access the repo.
```

I am really confused on where this error is coming from. This is my first time trying to upload a package to GitHub, and I just wanted to check if the package can be installed before I turned it in to my teacher. Here is a bit of code to test the functions if anyone needs it:

```
vec <- runif(100)

sample_mean(vec, 50)
many_sample_means(vec, reps = 10, n = 50)
sample_means_ns(vec, reps = 10, ns = c(5, 50, 500))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not yet created a package. You've just created some files with R code in them. An R package has a very particular structure that includes things like a DESCRIPTION file and a NAMESPACE file. In theory you could create these yourself, but often it's easier to use things like `devtools::create` and `roxygen` to create them for you. Or if you are using RStudio, you can create a new R Package project with default versions of these files.

To add a DESCRIPTION File, try running

```
usethis::use_description()
```

That will fill in defaults you can change.

Then you will need to create a NAMESPACE file. If you just want to make all the functions you define inside your R files to be available outside the pacakge, you can just put

```
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
```

in that file and that should work.

You might also consider following guides like thoses http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/package.html or https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/08-making-packages-R/ for a better overview on creating a package.

Once your repo looks like a proper R package, then you can use `devtools::install_github` to install it.

Note that github can be useful for tracking changes to any types of files. You may perform an analysis in an R script that you would like to track changes for and save that on github but it may not make sense to turn that analysis script into a packages. You generally make packages when you want to reuse functions or data across different projects then those projects can install and load your package. So not all R code lives inside an R package, but `devtools::install_github` can only be used to install actual packages.

Comment: I created this package by making a Rproject file and connecting it to a GitHub repository. I thought that made these defaults automatically?

Comment: An R Project file is different from an R Package. You can use files and scripts outside of a package. A package is really a collection of functions and data that you want to make reusable for other projects.

Comment: Hannah, unfortunately, there are more files required before R will consider it a *package*. I find http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/ to be a good resource for how to create a package; at least initially, you can probably skip topics of documentation, vignettes, tests, compiled code, etc ... but at least the structure and updating it (e.g., `devtools::document(...)` and `devtools::load_all(...)`) are important.

Comment: (And then once you have the basics down, I *strongly encourage* some form of documentation, where `roxygen2` is an easy start. There's nothing more frustrating than looking at your own code 2 months later and not being able to recall what arguments mean, etc. It is a bit more than just comments in the source.)

Comment: Thanks both of you for all your help! I followed the instructions and I think I have the basics down. My package is now uploaded here: https://github.com/hharder74/SampleMeansIII/ . I was able to install it using devtools::install_github, but when I try to use the functions from the package, it says they are not found. I must be missing one more step...

Comment: @HannahHarder, after installing, make sure you load your package with `library(SampleMeansIII)`

Comment: Yeah I did that. Two of the three functions are working fine, while the third one says not found.

Comment: I finally got it! I changed the name of the function and committed and pushed those changes, but I must have messed up because when I pushed again it worked.

Comment: @HannahHarder Glad that worked. If you make any changes to the package code, you will need to reinstall and load. It may be easier to use `devtools::load_all()` rather than going to github each time during development. But good luck. Hope this is just the first of many packages you make.